# Review action bar alignment

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review

The review action bar seems to have grown a bit... The "Skip" button is trying to escape too.

[image]

It doesn't matter how many buttons there are, the bar sticks out of the page wrapping anyway (W8, FF 57.0.2)

[image]

Comment: Similar bug report on english.SE: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11027/skip-skipped-to-new-line